# MySql SUM not returning any results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get the sum off all the prize money from a column in a MySql table, but I'm not getting a result.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT SUM(prize_money) FROM cards");
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $rows['SUM(prize_money)'];
}
```

I just want to add all of the numbers in the prize_money column then echo the results.
Thank You

Comment: Check for errors on the query execution. The `mysqli_query` procedural approach requires the connection link as parameter 1.

Comment: Rakesh Sojitra, thanks that is really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply an [alias](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-alias/) to the `SUM` so it is easier to access in the PHP.

You then need to pass the connection string to the `mysqli_query` function as the first parameter.

So for example if your database connection were:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

then you'd use this code to execute the query and assign the alias:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT SUM(prize_money) AS sum_prize_money FROM cards'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['sum_prize_money'];
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but still no joy.

Comment: Have you connected your database? Check database connection.

Comment: Thanks Nitin, I didnt copy the last semicolon, your code works a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a result if you do this:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT SUM(prize_money) FROM cards");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $rows
```

As good practice, you should learn to aliase your sql variables e.g. SUM(prize_money) AS total etc

Comment: Hi Leo, tried that but still no luck. I added the semicolon. Not sure why its not returning anything.

Comment: If i run "SELECT SUM(prize_money) FROM cards" in MySql viewer  I get the result.

Comment: Which version of php are you running?

Comment: Current PHP version: 7.1.1630699

Comment: Thanks for your help Leo, its much appreciated.